# .net change some characters of url before rewriting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working at mvc.net web application and I'm using urlrewritingNet for route urls.

I want to change some characters of url before urlrewriting reach url.

ex:

user request this url `/Prods/1/Medi_lice.aspx`

I want this url to be `/Prods/1/Medi-lice` before rewriting process.

Thanks

**Edit**

My question is: I want to change last segment of my url. I want the *underscore*  to be *dash*

I write HttpModule to work around:

```
public class PageNameProcessingModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.LogRequest += new EventHandler(App_Handler);
        context.PostLogRequest += new EventHandler(App_Handler);
    }

    public void App_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = app.Context;

        if (context.CurrentNotification == RequestNotification.LogRequest)
        {
            if (!context.IsPostNotification)
            {
                var url = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
                var segments = context.Request.Url.Segments;
                var lastSeg = segments[segments.Length - 1];
                segments[segments.Length - 1] = lastSeg.Replace("_", "-");

                // here I want an approach to set new url
                // or pass the new url to the UrlRewriting

                // this is urlrewriting namespace UrlRewritingNet.Configuration
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my question after I read [urlrewriting pdf](http://blog.thomasbandt.de/content/binary/UrlRewritingNet20.English.pdf)

I did the following:

- Write a custom provider
- Write custom rewrite rule.
- Update configs at web.config

Here is the custom provider:

```
public class CustomReWriteProvider : UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.Provider.UrlRewritingProvider
{
    public override UrlRewritingNet.Web.RewriteRule CreateRewriteRule()
    {
        return new CustomRegexReWriteRule();
    }
}
```

And here is the custom rewrite rule:

```
public class CustomRegexReWriteRule : UrlRewritingNet.Web.RewriteRule
{
    public override void Initialize(UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.RewriteSettings rewriteSettings)
    {
        base.Initialize(rewriteSettings);
        this.RegexOptions = rewriteSettings.GetEnumAttribute<RegexOptions>("regexOptions", RegexOptions.None);
        this.VirtualUrl = rewriteSettings.GetAttribute("virtualUrl", "");
        this.destinationUrl = rewriteSettings.GetAttribute("destinationUrl", "");
    }

    public override bool IsRewrite(string requestUrl)
    {
        return this.regex.IsMatch(requestUrl);
    }

    public override string RewriteUrl(string url)
    {
        string newUrl = url;
        if (url.ToLower().EndsWith(".aspx"))
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com" + url);
            var segments = uri.Segments;
            var lastSeg = segments[segments.Length - 1];
            var name = lastSeg.Remove(lastSeg.Length - 5);
            if (!name.IsNumbersOnly())
            {
                segments[segments.Length - 1] = lastSeg.Replace("_", "-");

                newUrl = string.Join("", segments) + uri.Query;
            }
        }
        return this.regex.Replace(newUrl, destinationUrl, 1);
    }

    private Regex regex;
    private void CreateRegEx()
    {
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper();
        if (IgnoreCase)
        {
            this.regex = new Regex(urlHelper.HandleRootOperator(virtualUrl), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | regexOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            this.regex = new Regex(urlHelper.HandleRootOperator(virtualUrl), RegexOptions.Compiled | regexOptions);
        }
    }

    private string virtualUrl = string.Empty;
    public string VirtualUrl
    {
        get { return virtualUrl; }
        set
        {
            virtualUrl = value;
            CreateRegEx();
        }
    }

    private string destinationUrl = string.Empty;
    public string DestinationUrl
    {
        get { return destinationUrl; }
        set { destinationUrl = value; }
    }

    private RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
    public RegexOptions RegexOptions
    {
        get { return regexOptions; }
        set
        {
            regexOptions = value; 
            CreateRegEx();
        }
    }
}
```

And at the configs:

```
<urlrewritingnet rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true" contextItemsPrefix="QueryString" defaultProvider="CutsomProvider" xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07" >
    <providers>
      <add name="CutsomProvider" type="MyNamespace.CustomReWriteProvider" />
    </providers>
</urlrewritingnet>
```

And It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try context.RewritePath method

Comment: It's not working.  I think I have to use urlrewriting

Comment: Run context.RewritePath in Begin_Request event. Sometime ago I did the same on my project and it worked fine...

Comment: but I'm using urlrewriting. so the url is processed by urlrewriting before Begin_Request event.  
I want to process the url before urlrewriting

Comment: I looked inside their dll with reflector and I can see that they use Begin_Request event. Here is the code: https://gyazo.com/aa93f243fb83e77158a4e7e29bd96a88 Also make sure that you declared your HttpModule before UrlRewriting module in config file...

Comment: Ok, but maybe it makes sense to update your regex in UrlRewriting module and work with ".aspx" at the end? It should be pretty easy and in this case you do not need to have one more Http module